# Can I customize the access log in my GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine logs each HTTP request in a line similar to what I used to see in Apache HTTP or Tomcat.
Below is a line from the logs:

`198.138.224.81 - - [13/Apr/2012:12:15:05 -0700] "GET /page/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4290 "http://APP-ID.appspot.com/add/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0" "3.APP-ID.appspot.com" ms=28 cpu_ms=210 api_cpu_ms=187 cpm_usd=0.006356 instance=01cb1aaa653f13c0586eac9964cc136`

Is it possible to add more content to the logs ? In my particular case, my application issues a challenge for [BASIC authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which adds a header to HTTP request, and I want to log that.

How can I customize the logs to also contain this header from the HTTP request ?

My app is written in Java, if that's any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no facility for customizing the default log. I don't see a feature request for it on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). Submit one and see if it gets some traction.

Comment: You'll have to provide a compelling reason why doing so is better than the existing logging support.

Answer (score 1):

Of course App Engine [supports logging](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Logging):

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

        log.info("Header your-header-name="+req.getHeader("your-header-name"));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nice, but can I customize the *default* log issued by the platform ?

Comment: No, you can not change the standard log statement that is produced for every request. Your logged statements will be added just below the standard log statement.